# How do I iterate nested API response in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to iterate a nested API response and display them inside a html. I managed to do single image because the response only have single value.

**API response **

```
{"result":{"totalResults":5861511,"products":[{"productTitle":"S-XL Plus Size Tunic Autumn <font><b>Women</b></font> Dresses Casual Cartoon Print Christmas Dress Casual Loose Long Sleeve Party Dress Vestidos","originalPrice":"US $7.98","imageUrl":"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H3ba2899c892d4a88a5f704453c39942ae/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg","productUrl":"https://www.aliexpress.com/item/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-Women-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas-Dress-Casual-Loose-Long/4000353066650.html","allImageUrls":"https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H3ba2899c892d4a88a5f704453c39942ae/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H218b19ee8bfc4f6ebe74b4297ca8395f5/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H14b48746d6eb4d5788a7a9f6ce37195c7/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hb4b1f8b6223d4e7c88208751bfa681886/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hcfd17f95ac85470d9550d13f3683adc1I/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg}]},"errorCode":20010000,"currentPageNum":0,"totalPageNum":0}
```

**main.js**

```
    $(function (){

        var $orders = $('#orders');
        var $productimage = $('#productimage');
        var $output = $('#output');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://gw.api.alibaba.com/openapi/param2/2/portals.open/api.listPromotionProduct/9420?fields=productUrl,allImageUrls,imageUrl,originalPrice,productTitle&keywords=women',
            success: function(orders){
                $.each(orders, function(i, order){

                    $orders.append('<a href="' + order.products[0].productUrl + '">' + order.products[0].productTitle + '</a>');
                    $output.append(order.products[0].allImageUrls[1]);

                    // $productimage.append('<img class="pic-1" src="' + order.products[0].imageUrl + '">');  // single image

                });
            }
        });


    });
```

**Result generated**

`"t"`

How do you create a loop for `$output` from `allImageUrls` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the allImageUrls and then run them in a loop as follows:

```js
var result ={
  "result": {
    "totalResults": 5861511,
    "products": [
      {
        "productTitle": "S-XL Plus Size Tunic Autumn <font><b>Women</b></font> Dresses Casual Cartoon Print Christmas Dress Casual Loose Long Sleeve Party Dress Vestidos",
        "originalPrice": "US $7.98",
        "imageUrl": "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H3ba2899c892d4a88a5f704453c39942ae/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg",
        "productUrl": "https://www.aliexpress.com/item/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-Women-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas-Dress-Casual-Loose-Long/4000353066650.html",
        "allImageUrls": "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H3ba2899c892d4a88a5f704453c39942ae/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H218b19ee8bfc4f6ebe74b4297ca8395f5/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H14b48746d6eb4d5788a7a9f6ce37195c7/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hb4b1f8b6223d4e7c88208751bfa681886/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg,https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hcfd17f95ac85470d9550d13f3683adc1I/S-XL-Plus-Size-Tunic-Autumn-font-b-Women-b-font-Dresses-Casual-Cartoon-Print-Christmas.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  "errorCode": 20010000,
  "currentPageNum": 0,
  "totalPageNum": 0
}

var allImagesList = result.result.products[0].allImageUrls.split(',');
allImagesList.forEach((imageUrl)=>{
console.log(imageUrl);
})
```

**And your code will look like something as below:**

```
    $(function (){

            var $orders = $('#orders');
            var $productimage = $('#productimage');
            var $output = $('#output');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://gw.api.alibaba.com/openapi/param2/2/portals.open/api.listPromotionProduct/9420?fields=productUrl,allImageUrls,imageUrl,originalPrice,productTitle&keywords=women',
                success: function(orders){
                    $.each(orders, function(i, order){

                        $orders.append('<a href="' + order.products[0].productUrl + '">' + order.products[0].productTitle + '</a>');
                        $output.append(order.products[0].allImageUrls[1]);

var allImagesList = order.products[0].allImageUrls.split(',');
allImagesList.forEach((imageUrl)=>{
$productimage.append('<img class="pic-1" src="' + imageUrl + '">');  // single image
})


                    });
                }
            });


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(orders, function(i, order) {
   $orders.append('<a href="' + order.products[0].productUrl + '">' + order.products[0].productTitle + '</a>');
      //------------------------Start 
      var allImageUrlsArray = []; // Create array;
      //split with comma, assign to varaible and loop it.
      allImageUrlsArray = order.products[0].allImageUrls.split(',');
      for (var i = 0; i < allImageUrlsArray.length; i++) {
          $output.append(allImageUrlsArray[i]);
      }
      //---------------------------End 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You did some mistakes in iterate JSON Object, and allImageUrls contain multiple images with comma(,) so you should convert this into array. Let's check the below example

LN: 21 you can loop the allImageUrls

```
for([k, v] of Object.entries(value.allImageUrls)){
  console.log(k, v);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="orders"></div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var $orders = $('#orders');
    var $productimage = $('#productimage');
    var $output = $('#output');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://gw.api.alibaba.com/openapi/param2/2/portals.open/api.listPromotionProduct/9420?fields=productUrl,allImageUrls,imageUrl,originalPrice,productTitle&keywords=women',
      success: function(item) {
        let orders = item.result.products;
        orders = orders.map(product => {
          product.allImageUrls = product.allImageUrls.split(',');
          return product;
        });
        var con = '';
        for ([key, value] of Object.entries(orders)) {
          con += "<li><a href='" + value.productUrl + "'><img style='width: 30px;' src='" + value.allImageUrls[0] + "'/>" + value.productTitle + "</a></li>";
          // Loop all images 
          for ([k, v] of Object.entries(value.allImageUrls)) {
            console.log(k, v);
          }
        }
        $orders.append("<ul>" + con + "</ul>");
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

  var $orders = $('#orders');
  var $productimage = $('#productimage');
  var $output = $('#output');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://gw.api.alibaba.com/openapi/param2/2/portals.open/api.listPromotionProduct/9420?fields=productUrl,allImageUrls,imageUrl,originalPrice,productTitle&keywords=women',
    success: function(orders) {
      $.each(orders.result.products, function(i, order) {
        console.log(order)
        $div = $('<div id = "' + "order_" + i + '"></div>');
        $imageDiv = $('<div id = "' + "image_" + i + '"></div>');
        // = $('#order_' + i);
        console.log($div)
        $div.append('<a href="' + order.productUrl + '">' + order.productTitle + '</a>');
        //;
        var array = order.allImageUrls.split(',');
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
          //$output.append(order.allImageUrls[j]);

          $imageDiv.append('<img style="width:50px;height:50px" class="pic-1" src="' + array[j] + '">'); // single image

        }


        $div.append($imageDiv);
        $orders.append($div);



      });
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">

  <div id="orders">



  </div>
</div>
```

> Hope this helps. :)